# docker-compose: Exposing port of docker image to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose.yml snippet which is intended to expose a SOAP endpoint in Java built by Maven to other docker images (not included in snippet, but they work):

`mocksumma:
    image: openjdk:9-jdk
    ports:
    - "56808:56808"
    expose: [56808]
    volumes:
    - ./mocksumma/target/mocksumma-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/mocksumma.jar
    #command: "sleep 10000000000"
    command: "java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar /mocksumma.jar 'http://localhost:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'"`

I would also like to access this from my host environment (Ubuntu 17.04, docker compose 1.8.1, docker 1.12.6), but when accessing http://localhost:56808 I get either connection closed or ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED.    The web service has been confirmed to be responsive using "telnet localhost 56808" inside the container itself).  Telnet from the host immediately returns connection closed:

`$ telnet localhost 56808
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

My theory is that for some reason the port is not exposed or forwarded (ports) to the host, because I have either overlooked or misunderstood something.

Suggestions?

Comment: If it is working with telnet inside the container then try to test it with telnet from your host system too (instead of using the browser there). This facilitates the troubleshooting.

Comment: @YannicHamann Added telnet output

Comment: You port config is fine. The client is able to connect. Seems to be another problem. Gets the connection immediately closed inside the container when you use telnet there?

Comment: @YannicHamann Interesting.  Now that fails too.  I'll leave for today now, and come back to this tomorrow.  Thanks so far.

Comment: Apparently there was some mixup of containers.  I redid it very carefully and now `curl -O 'http://localhost:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'         ` inside the container gives me the expected file, so it is definitively working.  The same command on the host still gives a connection broken message from curl.

Comment: If port was not exposed then you should receive "Connection refused" exception. It seems like application inside container drops connection for any reason.

Comment: Try changing your command to `command: "java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar /mocksumma.jar 'http://0.0.0.0:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Interesting detail.  I did not think of the possibility that the request came from another network interface.

Comment: Localhost inside container is local to the container only, so if something works inside container and not outside then it is either interface issue or wrong port mapping. And I knew latter is not the case. Btw you didn't mention if it worked or not?

Comment: @TarunLalwani It made immediate sense when you pointed it out.  I just didn't think of it.  I have just tested it now, and as expected it fixed the issue.  If you make an answer with an explanation, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your command to

```
command: "java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar /mocksumma.jar 'http://0.0.0.0:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'"
```

So the updated compose file will be

```
 mocksumma:
    image: openjdk:9-jdk
    ports:
    - "56808:56808"
    expose: [56808]
    volumes:
    - ./mocksumma/target/mocksumma-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/mocksumma.jar
    #command: "sleep 10000000000"
    command: "java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar /mocksumma.jar 'http://0.0.0.0:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'"
```

Looking at the command which worked inside container, I assumed that your `mocksumma.jar` file binds to network interfaces based on the argument url. This means when you use use url as `http://0.0.0.0:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl` it binds to `localhost:56808`.

Now inside a container `localhost` will point to the container's loopback interface and it will only answer when the traffic comes from inside the container itself. When you try to map this port or another container tries to reach this container at `56808` the request is coming on `eth0` or similar interface of the container.

But your bind is only to `localhost:56808`. To solve the issue you need to bind it to all available interfaces which can be done by binding to `0.0.0.0:56808`. `0.0.0.0` is a special IPv4 address which is used for binding to all available interfaces

Comment: You are right.  It is very important to understand that networking is more complex when using Docker or similar, than when just running on your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format, like the documentation

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

Example

```
 mocksumma:
image: openjdk:9-jdk
ports:
- "56808:56808"
expose: 
- "56808"
volumes:
- ./mocksumma/target/mocksumma-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/mocksumma.jar
#command: "sleep 10000000000"
command: "java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar /mocksumma.jar 'http://localhost:56808/mediehub/search/services/SearchWS?wsdl'"
```